# addSubView - adding a button inside a UIView adds the same button for it's SuperView as well

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am following this tutorial to create a rating button - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html

I created a UIView inside a UIViewController inside the Storyboard by drag and drop and that UIView is controlled by the below class.

```
class RatingControl: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 320, height: 44)
    }

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed ")
    }
}
```

The problem is when I add the UIButton, it's showing two buttons, one in it's parent UIViewController at location (x:0, y:0) in addition to the one inside the UIView. I want the button to be showing only inside the UIView inside the UIViewController.

I researched ways to prevent it, one way is to add these buttons manually in the storyboard instead of creating them in the init, but then I am curious how it works fine in the tutorial. I am using iOS 8.3.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have subclassed the UIViewControllers view class also to RatingControl and also the view that you have added because of which it is showing it twice. Kindly check it  because it works proper if u only add it to the view you need

[image]

If you have added the subclass to the ViewControllers view as well you would get this , which is as per your scenario

[image]

Comment: Would you mind elaborating, I tried my best to understand your statement, I believe it's a step in the right direction to solving this. Inside a UIViewController in Main storyboard, I dragged and dropped an UIView, set it's class as RatingControl that extends UIView and added the above methods.

Comment: I have tried the code you have pasted and it works proper, i meant you must have subclassed the ViewControllers View to RatingControl, in that case it is getting added on the super view along with your subView

Comment: Please check the edited answer and is that what you are getting, and also have a look at the ViewControllers view which is also set to Rating control and that is the reason you are getting the button on the superView as well. In the first image that i have added the view that i have put on storyboard only that is subclassed to RatingControl and it works as per your requirement. Could you attach your storyboard image as well

Comment: Spot on (attached the screenshot in the description). This is the problem, I have been coding for a while and little did I pay attention to this when dragging and dropping items to Storyboard. Let me fix this stuff and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try instead of

```
addSubview(button)
```

this:

```
view.addSubview(button)
```

it will add this button to your viewController